# how to validate nested Model with the flattened input with Pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic, protobuf-c

support the input is

```
input_dict = {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3",
    "field4": "value4",
}
```

the models I created are(you can rewrite it, I just want to get the desired output)

```
class Model1(BaseModel):
    field1: str
    field2: str

class Model2(BaseModel):
    model1: Model1
    field3: str
```

so **how to validate the input**? the desired output should be:

```
Model2(**input_dict).model_dump()
{
    "model1": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
    },
    "field3": "value3",
}
```

Please feel free to ask for more details if I didn't express it clearly.

thanks in advance!!!

#### You can ignore the below

the background is that the flattened input is from the request body, and the desired output will be used to construct protobuf which requires the nested output.

the protobuf should be

```
message event2 {
    message event1 {
        str field1 = 1
        str field2 = 2
    }
    str field3 = 1
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to validate that the input matches the class structure, or how to go from the input to the class structure? If the latter, you can't easily, because they don't match.